# Bootstrap 5, content slides behind sidebar when screen resizes

Tags: css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-5

I'm building a sidebar, and so far its looking good . The only issue I have been struggling with for days now, is that when I show a new page and then resize the screen, the page content slides behind the sidebar. Is there any way to prevent this form happening ? I dont want the sidebar to resize as the screen shrinks. Below is the code form my _layout page, I'm hoping someone can spot what I'm doing wrong.

```
<style>
    #sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        width: 250px;
        z-index: 1000;
        left: 0;
        top: 68px;
        bottom: 60px;
        display: block;
        background-color: rgb(95,131,183);
    }
    .nav-item {
        border-bottom-color: #9EB4D3 !important;
        word-spacing: 10px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        
    }
    .nav-link:hover {
        background-color: #373443;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home">
                    <img src="~/images/LogoGrey.png" style="width:140px; margin-left: 30px"/>
                </a>
                <div class="d-flex" style="height: 40px; margin-left: 50px">
                    <div class="vr"></div>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <i class="bi bi-search" style="margin-right: 20px; font-size:larger"></i>
                <i class="bi bi-bell" style="margin-right: 20px; font-size:larger"></i>
                <div class="d-flex" style="height: 40px; margin-right:20px">
                    <div class="vr"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="float-right">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail rounded-circle" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/img%20(30).jpg">
                    Jane Doe
                </span>
                <div class="d-flex" style="height: 40px; margin-left:20px" >
                    <div class="vr"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="form-label" style="padding-left:20px; margin-right: 20px; padding-top: 5px">
                    Logout
                </span>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Side Nav-->
    <nav class="navbar">
        <nav class="navbar-nav">
            <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
                <ul class="nav flex-column" id="nav_accordion">
                    <li class="nav-item border-bottom">
                        <a class="nav-link bi bi-house" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" style="color: whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Home </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item border-bottom">
                        <a class="nav-link  bi bi-speedometer" href="#" style="color: whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Dashboard  </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item has-submenu border-bottom">
                        <a class="nav-link bi bi-gear" href="#" style="color:whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Setup </a>
                        <ul class="submenu collapse" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color:rgb(115,141,190);">
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> General Settings </a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Regions</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Stores</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Service Areas</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Departments</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Categories</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item has-submenu border-bottom">
                        <a class="nav-link bi bi-people" href="#" style="color: whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Contacts  </a>
                        <ul class="submenu collapse" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color:rgb(115,141,190)">
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" asp-area="" asp-controller="Users" asp-action="UsersIndex" style="color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Users </a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Customers </a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Suppliers </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item has-submenu border-bottom">
                        <a class="nav-link bi bi-journal-text" href="#" style="color: whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Recipes  </a>
                        <ul class="submenu collapse" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color:rgb(115,141,190)">
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Products </a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Components </a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Finished Products </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="navbar-light bg-light footer">
        <div class="col-4" style="margin-left:10px">
            <label>
                &copy; 2022 - TasteWise International
            </label>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Many thanks
AJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the sidebar on the left and page content on the right, they should be placed in the same parent div. Then control the width of the two part of the div.

Change your code below:

```
<style>
    #sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        width: 250px;
        z-index: 1000;
        left: 0;
        top: 68px;
        bottom: 60px;
        display: block;
        background-color: rgb(95,131,183);
    }
    .main {
        margin-left: 250px; /* Same width as the sidebar + left position in px */
    }
    .nav-item {
        border-bottom-color: #9EB4D3 !important;
        word-spacing: 10px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        
    }
    .nav-link:hover {
        background-color: #373443;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home">
                    <img src="~/images/LogoGrey.png" style="width:140px; margin-left: 30px"/>
                </a>
                <div class="d-flex" style="height: 40px; margin-left: 50px">
                    <div class="vr"></div>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <i class="bi bi-search" style="margin-right: 20px; font-size:larger"></i>
                <i class="bi bi-bell" style="margin-right: 20px; font-size:larger"></i>
                <div class="d-flex" style="height: 40px; margin-right:20px">
                    <div class="vr"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="float-right">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail rounded-circle" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/img%20(30).jpg">
                    Jane Doe
                </span>
                <div class="d-flex" style="height: 40px; margin-left:20px" >
                    <div class="vr"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="form-label" style="padding-left:20px; margin-right: 20px; padding-top: 5px">
                    Logout
                </span>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
                              <!-- modify start-->

<div class="container">
    <!-- Side Nav-->
    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
        <ul class="nav flex-column" id="nav_accordion">
            <li class="nav-item border-bottom">
                <a class="nav-link bi bi-house" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" style="color: whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Home </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item border-bottom">
                <a class="nav-link  bi bi-speedometer" href="#" style="color: whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Dashboard  </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item has-submenu border-bottom">
                <a class="nav-link bi bi-gear" href="#" style="color:whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Setup </a>
                <ul class="submenu collapse" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color:rgb(115,141,190);">
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> General Settings </a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Regions</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Stores</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Service Areas</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Departments</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Categories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item has-submenu border-bottom">
                <a class="nav-link bi bi-people" href="#" style="color: whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Contacts  </a>
                <ul class="submenu collapse" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color:rgb(115,141,190)">
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" asp-area="" asp-controller="Users" asp-action="UsersIndex" style="color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Users </a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Customers </a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Suppliers </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item has-submenu border-bottom">
                <a class="nav-link bi bi-journal-text" href="#" style="color: whitesmoke; padding-left: 10px"> Recipes  </a>
                <ul class="submenu collapse" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color:rgb(115,141,190)">
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Products </a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Components </a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link bi bi-caret-right" href="#" style=" color: whitesmoke; word-spacing: normal; padding-left: 50px"> Finished Products </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="main">

        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
                              <!-- modify end-->

    <footer class="navbar-light bg-light footer">
        <div class="col-4" style="margin-left:10px">
            <label>
                &copy; 2022 - TasteWise International
            </label>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```